# Read Content from Payload and send email in Mule Email Connector

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4, mule-esb

I am working on a mule. While working I came across a scenario, where I want to send an email to the person, where I want to read some Ids from the payload (vars).

Basically, I want to append some static data along with the payload/variables in the email body content.

While writing the piece of code I'm getting syntactical errors. Attached screen a shot.

Would anyone please suggest the fix/code?

[image: EmailError]

Comment: Please add the XML text snippet of that connector. The screenshot is useful to see the error but don't use a screenshot for code, logs or configurations that are really text. Note that the error here also hides part of the code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use expression delimiters `#[  ]` inside an expression. They should enclose the whole expression. In that particular field because the 'fx' button is clicked it is assumed that the contents are already an expression. If you see the XML view of that part you'll see the delimiters around the expression.

To resolve the error just remove them from around the variable.